# Want to export our report data in csv with the help of php "Only selected from dropdown filters"

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

This is my code which generates a report I want to export this report in csv.

```
public function productsellerreportAction(){    

     global $mySession ; 

     $this->view->pageHeading = "Product seller";

     $this->view->pageDescription = "Booking Report";

      //$sId =$this->_getParam('sId') ;

     //$storeData = $this->modelSuper->Super_Get('stores'," 1","fetchAll");

      //archana////

     if($this->adminLogged->admin_id==1){

         $storeData = $this->modelSuper->Super_Get('stores'," 1","fetchAll");

     }else{

      $store_array=array();

      $store_ids = $this->modelSuper->getAdapter()->query("select ash_store_id from acl_store_hq where ash_admin_id=".$this->adminLogged->admin_id)->fetchAll();

      foreach($store_ids as $s_i){

         $store_array[]=$s_i['ash_store_id'];

      }

      $store_array_ids = join("','",$store_array);  

      $storeData = $this->modelSuper->getAdapter()->query("select * from stores where s_id in ('$store_array_ids') ")->fetchAll();

     }

    //archana////

     $this->view->storeData=$storeData;

     $sd=$sdate =$this->_getParam('sdate') ;

     $ed=$edate =$this->_getParam('edate') ;

            $sId =$this->_getParam('store') ;

            $this->view->sId=$sId;

            $this->view->sd=$sd;

            $this->view->ed=$ed;

}





public function getproductsellerdataAction(){

    global $mySession ; 

    $this->dbObj = Zend_Registry::get('db');

    $sId=$this->_getParam('sId') ;





      $sd=$sdate =$this->_getParam('sd') ;

      $ed=$edate =$this->_getParam('ed') ;

      if($sdate==""){



      }else{

        $sdate=explode("-",$sdate);

        $sdate=$sdate[2].'-'.$sdate[1].'-'.$sdate[0];

      }

      if($edate==""){



      }else{

        $edate=explode("-",$edate);

        $edate=$edate[2].'-'.$edate[1].'-'.$edate[0];

      }


      //'SUM(bp_qty) as bp_qty1','SUBSTRING(bp_resn, 1, 8) as bp_resn1','(bp_amount/bp_qty) as bp_rate2'

            $aColumns = array('b_id','bp_resn','bp_name','b_orderid','bp_qty','bp_amount','b_date','b_status','(bp_amount/bp_qty) as bp_rate2','cast(substr(b_orderid, 6) as unsigned) AS b_orderid1');

    $sIndexColumn = 'b_id';



    $sTable1 = ' booking ';


    $sTable = 'booking';

    /* 

     * Paging

     */

    $sLimit = "";

    if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )

    {

        $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );

    }

        /*
     * Ordering
     */
    $sOrder = "";

    if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
    {
        $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
        {
            if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
            {
                if($aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]=='b_orderid1'){
                       $sOrder .= "b_orderid1".
                    ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
                }
                else if($aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]=='b_date'){
                       $sOrder .= "b_date ".
                    ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
                }else{
                      $sOrder .= "".$aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]." ".
                    ($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
                }

            }
        }


        //prd($sOrder);
        $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
        if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
        {
            $sOrder = "";
        }
    }

    /* 
     * Filtering
     * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
     * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
     * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
     */
    $sWhere = "";
    if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) and $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= " LCASE(".$aColumns[$i].") LIKE '%".strtolower( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }

    /* Individual column filtering */
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) and $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" and $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
        {
            if ( $sWhere == "" )
            {
                $sWhere = "WHERE ";
            }
            else
            {
                $sWhere .= " AND ";
            }
            $sWhere .= "LCASE(".$aColumns[$i].") LIKE '%".strtolower($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";

            //$sWhere .= "".$aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$_GET['sSearch_'.$i]."%' ";
        }
    }



    if($sdate!=""){

        $con1=" and b_date>='".$sdate."'";

    }else {

        $con1='';

    }

    if($edate!=""){

        $con2=" and b_date<='".$edate."'";

    }else{

        $con2='';

    }

    if($sWhere==""){

        $sWhere=" where 1 ";



    }

    $con3="join booking_product on b_id=bp_b_id and b_booked_by=".$sId." and b_status <> '-1' ";





    $newsql=$con1. $con2;



    $sWhere.=" and ".$newsql;



    $sQuery = " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))." FROM  $sTable1 

    $con3  $newsql $sOrder $sLimit";
    //echo $sQuery; die;



    $qry = $this->dbObj->query($sQuery)->fetchAll();



    //echo "<pre>"; var_dump($qry); echo "</pre>"; die;



    /* Data set length after filtering */

    $sQuery = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as fcnt";



    $aResultFilterTotal =  $this->dbObj->query($sQuery)->fetchAll(); 

    $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0]['fcnt'];



    /* Total data set length */

    $sQuery = "SELECT COUNT(`".$sIndexColumn."`) as cnt FROM $sTable1 $con3 ".$newsql ;

    $rResultTotal = $this->dbObj->query($sQuery)->fetchAll(); 

    $iTotal = $rResultTotal[0]['cnt'];



    /*

     * Output

     */





         $output = array(

            "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,

            "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,

            "aaData" => array()

         );



    $j=0;$i=1; $count=1;



    foreach($qry as $row12)

    {  

         $row=array();

         $row[]=$count; 

         $row[]=$row12['bp_resn'];

         $row[]=$row12['bp_name'];     

         $row[]=$row12['b_orderid'];

         $row[]=$row12['bp_qty'];

    //   $row[]=$row12['b_date'];

        $row[]= number_format((float)$row12['bp_rate2'], 2, '.', '');

         //$row[]=$row12['bp_total'];
         $output['aaData'][] = $row;

         $j++; $i++; $count++;

    }   



    echo json_encode($output);

    exit();

}
```

This is php code.

This is result which comes after selecting store and dates:

[image]

Comment: That's a lot of code to ask people to look through. I am not sure what the problem is, though - what problem do you want people to see in the final image?

Comment: Right...so you need to get the same data and turn it into CSV instead of HTML. What's gone wrong when you do that? You forgot to tell us what your issue is, or ask us anything. "I want to" doesn't constitute a valid question on here. We're not a free write-my-code-from-vague-requirements service. We'll help you fix a specific problem, if you've made some attempt to solve it yourself in the first place. So...what difficulty are you facing?